# Lift (elevator) and equivalence principle

Tags: equivalence-principle, escape-velocity

A famous example to explain the equivalence principle is a lift (elevator) in the space (no gravity field), moving up with the acceleration of "g". It is said there is no way (experiment) that one can tell he/she is inside the moving lift (acceleration of g) or inside a lift that is stationary on earth.

Now, consider this experiment: if we think of earth escape velocity, if we shoot a bullet with earth escape velocity (or faster), it will never come back if we are on earth, but if we are in the moving lift, we eventually reach the bullet.

How can we explain this?

Comment: The claim is that there are no _local_ experiments that can tell the difference, so I believe here the full answer would be vindicated by explaining why this shows a _global_ property of the spacetime, in other words just showing that the geodesics in Rindler coordinates start off similar to the geodesics of the Schwarzschild solution but the eventual overtaking of the bullet in Rindler coordinates is an effect of higher-order... It seems intuitively plausible since the Rindler coordinates probably take a while to catch up to the bullet so it spends a lot of time "out there."

Comment: One can also distinguish an elevator from earth (very precisely) by measuring the apparent gravitational field at two points: one close to the floor, one high up. Since the gravitational field on earth is not actually uniform, one would see variation in the field strength on earth, but not in the elevator. Both your experiment and this one are using non-local effects, so they do not contradict the equivalence principle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Earth’s escape velocity is finite because the force of gravity decreases with increasing distance from the Earth’s centre. However, a lift  with constant acceleration is equivalent to a *uniform* gravitational field which does not decrease with distance.

For a uniform gravitational field there is no finite escape velocity - no matter how fast we fire a bullet it will eventually fall back to Earth again. Equivalently, no matter how fast we fire a bullet the accelerating lift will eventually catch up with it.